# Uninstalling a "non-package-manager application"

Tags: software-installation

I installed Jetbrains' Gogland and tried it out. In the end I decided against it and wanted to uninstall it. The thing is that I did not install it with apt-get, but I just downloaded a .tar.gz file from their website. I had to run a .sh file to start it and then install it. In order to uninstall it I just removed the folder where all the files were saved. Is there something else I need to do ?

I tried the following command to check if there are any other files on the pc, but did not find anything :

```
sudo find .  -name "*gogland*" -print
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a "non-package-manager application", which can be difficult to uninstall completely. It depends on whether the application creates files outside its initial directory, and if so, whether they are easily found.

A "non-package-manager application" is typically installed by:

- downloading it to a user folder
- navigating to the folder and running an executable

  - the executable may simply **run** the application from its current location (as is the case for Gogland), or it may **install** the application by copying it to another directory
  - one may run the executable as a **user** (as is the case for Gogland) or as **root**

I took a quick look at Gogland. From what I saw, the executable only runs the application, without installing it anywhere else; thus, "uninstalling" Gogland is achieved by simply removing its directory....unless you also want to remove any generated supplementary files (configuration files, cache files, etc).

To find them, the first step would be to check whether they are declared in the official documentation. Gogland seems to have done this in the "Installation Instructions" file, which cites `~/.Gogland1.0` as the configuration/cache directory. Deleting this folder completes the removal of Gogland files from your system.

## inotify

In the absence of documentation, one could try using `inotify`, which monitors file system events. By setting `inotify` to monitor the user's entire home directory tree, then running Gogland, one can watch its management of supplementary files. (Monitoring can be restricted to the home directory since Gogland is run as a user, and therefore cannot modify files outside `~`).

I tried running `inotifywait -mr -e create,modify ~`. This command recursively (`-r`) monitors directory `~` for any file creation or modification events (`-e create,modify`). Monitoring is continuous (`-m`), as opposed to the default behaviour of monitoring only until the first event is detected.

I then launched Gogland. From my quick test, it appears that `~/.Gogland1.0` is indeed the application's only supplementary file location.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Checked again and deleted everything :)